# Create new variable by dividing column by observation in last row

Tags: stata

I want to create a new variable, say ***cheese2***, that takes ***cheese*** and divides every by the last observation (2921333).

```
     +----------+
     |   cheese |
     |----------|
  1. |  3060000 |
  2. | 840333.3 |
  3. |  1839667 |
  4. | 1.17e+07 |
  5. |  1374000 |
     |----------|
  6. |  2092333 |
  7. |   341000 |
  8. |  3149000 |
  9. |  3557667 |
 10. | 590666.7 |
     |----------|
 11. |  8937000 |
 12. |  4142000 |
 13. |  2624000 |
 14. |  1973667 |
 15. |  2921333 |
```

I would also like to do this for multiple columns at once i.e. divide multiple columns by the last row of my data set.

Answer (score 3):

In Stata terminology,

create a new variable by dividing a column by the observation in the last row

becomes

create a new variable by dividing a variable by the value in the last observation.

Such a question suggests that you are storing totals in your last observation, spreadsheet style. Such a practice is undoubtedly convenient for what you are asking, but it creates obligations to exclude the last observation from almost every other manipulation and to maintain precisely the same sort order, and would generally be considered a bad idea therefore.

All that said,

```
gen cheese2 = cheese/cheese[_N]
```

is what you ask and a loop over several variables could be

```
foreach v of var frog newt toad lizard dragon { 
       gen `v'2 = `v'/`v'[_N]
}
```

See also the help for `foreach`.

Comment: great, thanks for the thorough explanation and code.